# Markdown Markup Markleft Markright Editor

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, markdown

I have a blog that I occasionally post to, but it's a PITA because of the fact that it has it's own WYSIWYG editor and doesn't support Markdown. So I have to switch the WYSIWYG editor to the HTML editor, and of course the HTML is garbled from the WYSIWYG editor.

So, I wrote a programme that I can feed Markdown into, and it will let me see what the HTML would be, and a preview of how it would look. It's all very simple.

[image: Screenshot in Action]

The XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Markdown_Markup.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Markdown_Markup"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="297" Width="474"
        x:Name="_this">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StatusBar Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <Menu x:Name="menu" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="markdownTextBox" Margin="5,50,5,29" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.RowSpan="3" TextChanged="textBox_TextChanged" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True"/>
        <TextBox Margin="5,28,5,5" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" IsReadOnly="True" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=_this}" Text="{Binding Path=MarkdownHtml}"/>
        <TextBox Margin="5,26,5,29" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" IsReadOnly="True" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=_this}" Text="{Binding Path=RenderHtml}"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="styleTextBox" Margin="5,50,5,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="1" TextChanged="textBox_TextChanged" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True"/>
        <WebBrowser x:Name="renderPreviewBrowser" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5,50,5,29" Grid.RowSpan="3" Navigating="renderPreviewBrowser_Navigating" />
        <Label Content="Markdown Content:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label Content="Additional CSS:" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label Content="Markdown HTML:" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,2,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label Content="Render HTML:" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label Content="HTML Preview:" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The Code Behind:

```
using MarkdownSharp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Markdown_Markup
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MarkdownHtmlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MarkdownHtml", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

        public string MarkdownHtml
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(MarkdownHtmlProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(MarkdownHtmlProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty RenderHtmlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RenderHtml", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

        public string RenderHtml
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(RenderHtmlProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(RenderHtmlProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var markdown = new Markdown();
            var html = markdown.Transform(markdownTextBox.Text);

            MarkdownHtml = html;

            html = $"<html>\r\n\t<head>\r\n\t\t<style>\r\n\t\t\t{styleTextBox.Text}\r\n\t\t</style>\r\n\t</head>\r\n\t<body>\r\n\t\t{html}\r\n\t</body>\r\n</html>";
            RenderHtml = html;

            renderPreviewBrowser?.NavigateToString(html);
        }

        private void renderPreviewBrowser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            // This prevents links in the page from navigating, this also means we cannot call WebBrowser.Navigate for any browsers with this event.
            if (e.Uri != null)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you're going to run it, you need to install [`MarkdownSharp` from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MarkdownSharp/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to unleash the almighty power of WPF, and bind to a *ViewModel*; WPF and the *Model-View-ViewModel* design go completely hand-in-hand, especially if you like your code testable.

As it stands the only way to test the application logic is to actually run it and see what happens - that's good for a prototype app, but for an actual real-world app you'll want something a bit more robust.

Start with a class, and identify what your view needs - as always, input and output:

- **Input**

  - Some Markdown content
  - Some CSS content
- **Output**

  - The resulting HTML

Easy as pie. Your ViewModel could start like this:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _markdownContent;
    public string MarkdownContent
    {
        get { return _markdownContent; }
        set
        {
            _markdownContent = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _cssContent;
    public string CssContent
    {
        get { return _cssContent; }
        set
        {
            _cssContent = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _htmlContent;
    public string HtmlContent
    {
        get { return _htmlContent; }
        set
        {
            _htmlContent = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    // todo: INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
}
```

How is that used? I'll cheat a little and do this to illustrate:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
}

private MainWindowViewModel ViewModel
{
    get { return DataContext As MainWindowViewModel; }
}
```

Now your View knows about a ViewModel, and its `DataContext` is set to an instance of it. You'll probably want a better way to do this though, but that's just to get the ball rolling.

The MainWindow's `DataContext` will now be inherited by everything in the XAML that doesn't override it - get rid of all that `DataContext={foobar}` markup, you don't need it anymore.

Now you can do this (removed fluff for clarity):

```
<TextBox Content="{Binding MarkdownContent}"/>
<TextBox Content="{Binding CssContent}"/>
```

The `WebBrowser` is a [little more fun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4204350/1188513) (involves creating a *behavior* and an *attached property* - see the linked SO post), but at the end of the day boils down to this:

```
<WebBrowser local:BrowserBehavior.Html="{Binding HtmlContent}"/>
```

What does that entail? Whenever the markdown/css changes *inside the textboxes*, the ViewModel knows, because its setters are running - you have a handle to run your application logic, without writing a single line of code in the View's code-behind! No need to handle `TextChanged`, and no need to even *name* any of the controls!

Now, you can implement the application logic directly inside the ViewModel class, or better, you can constructor-inject the ViewModel with an object that's solely responsible for that.

Comment: Actually, it outputs *two* HTML strings.